# Python (SciTools) - error in the encoder when trying to make a movie (cannot save)

Tags: python, gif, encode, movie

I'm learning how to program in Python, and have been going through Langtangen's *A Primer on Scientific Programming with Python*. The book refers to a website that has book examples or working code samples/programs posted there (http://hplgit.github.io/scipro-primer/), and among those are also a couple that use SciTools (EasyViz), generate a couple of plots and then try to save them in a .gif file (which is the default output format for a movie, I guess).

The problem is that I get an error when I run the programs. I see the evolution through changing figures, but at the end when the program is supposed to save those .png files into a movie, I get the following error message:

```
Found 73 files of the format tmp_*.png.
scitools.easyviz.movie function runs the command: 
convert -delay 50 tmp_*.png tmp_heatwave.gif
Invalid Parameter - 50

scitools.easyviz.movie could not make movie
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Workspaces\Eclipse Python Workspace\Book Examples\src\plot\heatwave.py", line 41, in <module>
output_file='tmp_heatwave.gif')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scitools\easyviz\movie.py", line 1151, in movie
me.encode()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scitools\easyviz\movie.py", line 153, in encode
raise SystemError('Check error messages from the encoder in the terminal window')
SystemError: Check error messages from the encoder in the terminal window
```

I looked at the code in the movie module and the parameter 50 seems to refer to the delay in fps. For example, in another sample program, it's set to 4, and you also get the same return message. And if I delete that delay line in the module implemented in the SciTools bundle itself, the error would read:

```
Invalid Parameter - tmp_heatwave.gif
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on? I didn't change the code and I'm sure it's correct, yet I can't save movies as I'm supposed to!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same trouble (also learning from the same book).
For me it happened when I ran the `bisection_movie.py` file.

In my case the way I solved it was the following way:

1. In the  following website they mention that I needed to have the software  ImageMagick  installed, so I installed it [following the instructions listed here](https://code.google.com/p/scitools/wiki/EasyvizDocumentation#Trouble_with_Movie_Making).
2. Then after that I installed the python interface with ImageMagick called Python Magick (didn't know if I needed but I still did).
3. After all this I still was having troubles, and I decided to do what the error message suggested with was to check the command window  for the error message from the encoder. It was long but one of the pieces said

   > **`No such file or directory @ error/ps.c/ReadPSImage/837`**
4. After looking this error online, I found that what I still was missing was the "**Ghostscript delegate library**" (don't ask me what it is, i dont quite know). After installing the Ghostscript delegate library for windows (32 bit since that's what my python version is). It got solved and it was able to create the movie.

I would suggest installing the ghostscript delegate library first and check if that is enough. If it is, post back that it worked, so i know of all the damn things I did, what was it that made the code work.

Comment: Thanks. I currently don't have the time to check, and it's been a long time since I last programmed in Python, so that's the reason I haven't accepted your answer (yet). I appreciate the input, though, and will accept your answer as soon as I check it out.